# El siguiente código es para unir dos PDF, cuando intento abrir el resultante da error

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-drive

Cuando intento abrir el pdf resultante de correr el código que adjunto, me da el siguiente error:

[image: Error]

No he incluido los ID de los PDF en el código, pero se podría probar con cualquier pareja de PDF. El código está comentado.
Gracias por anticipado

```
function unirPDFsEnGoogleDrive() {
  // Ids de los archivos PDF en Google Drive que deseas unir
   const idDocumento1 = 'ID1';
  const idDocumento2 = 'ID2';
  

  // Obtener el contenido de los archivos PDF
  const contenidoDoc1 = obtenerContenidoPDF(idDocumento1);
  const contenidoDoc2 = obtenerContenidoPDF(idDocumento2);

  

  // Unir los contenidos de los PDFs
  
  const contenidoUnido = contenidoDoc1.concat(contenidoDoc2);
 
  // Crear un nuevo archivo PDF en Google Drive con el contenido unido
  const nuevoIdDocumento = crearNuevoDocumentoPDF(contenidoUnido);

  Logger.log(`Documentos PDF unidos con éxito. Nuevo ID de documento: ${nuevoIdDocumento}`);
}

function obtenerContenidoPDF(idDocumento) {
  const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/${idDocumento}?alt=media`;
  const respuesta = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`
    }
  });
  return respuesta.getBlob().getBytes();
}

function crearNuevoDocumentoPDF(contenido) {
  const nuevoNombre = 'documento_unido.pdf';

  const nuevoArchivo = DriveApp.createFile(nuevoNombre, contenido, 'application/pdf');
  return nuevoArchivo.getId();
}
```